# How to force Grid to shrink an auto sized row that contains ScrollViewer (when needed)?

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, scrollviewer

How would one create this layout?:

[image: How it should work]

The idea is to keep the blue text always just below the green element BUT when there is not enough space, the green element should be placed inside a scrollable container (with vertical scrollbar visible).

I have tried StackPanel and Grid and both failed. The StackPanel does not shrink rows at all. The Grid does the same if the top RowDefinition's height is set to "auto" (the ScrollViewer inside does not show its scrollbar). If it's set to a star, the blue text is moved down to at least half of the space (depends of the bottom row's height setting). The bottom row's height can be either an "auto" or a star with VerticalAlignment of the blue text set to Top BUT the row's height must be kept at least as big as the text's. Of course the whole area (black box) cannot be stretched by its content - it's determined by the size of the window.

How? Please keep the responses to be based on XAML if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inspired by Eirik's approach of constraining a greedy container by putting it inside other tight container, I've discovered a really simple way to achieve what I wanted. I only needed a container that shrinks its one child first, then (when the first one completely disappears) the second one. And there is such container: the DockPanel. Here goes:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1">Automatically wrapped text of unknown length.</TextBlock>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">In this case the element is too big to fit inside whole space (the black box) with the blue text below. I want the scrollbar to be shown instead of moving the blue text outside of the black box (and clipped)</TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

As simple as that! :) I hope it helps someone.

Comment: This did indeed help me. I was trying to do exactly the same thing and this worked a charm. Thanks for putting in your eventual solution!

Answer (score 3):

```
<Grid Name="outerGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas>
        <Grid MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=outerGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=outerGrid, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer Width="{Binding ElementName=outerGrid, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">In this case the element is too big to fit inside whole space (the black box) with the blue text below. I want the scrollbar to be shown instead of moving the blue text outside of the black box (and clipped)</TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1">Automatically wrapped text of unknown length.</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The auto height will grow to match the height of the content of that row.

The star height will let that row grow in height to fill the rest of the height of the grid, preventing the `ScrollViewer` to grow more than what's visible.

**Edit**: If you put the Grid inside another Grid like the XAML above you should get the behavior you want.
The second row of the outer row acts as a "filler" to fill the rest of the space the outer Grid.

**Edit 2**: Try the edited XAML above. I've put the inner `Grid` inside a `Canvas` (to prevent clipping) and bound the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` of the inner `Grid` to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the outer `Grid` to keep the inner `Grid` the same size as the outer `Grid`.

**Edit 3**: Added binding to the `Width` of the `ScrollViewer` to keep it the same width as the rest.

Comment: This would be good BUT I want the bottom (blue) text to be placed just below the upper element (as high as possible). In your example it is placed at the bottom of the window (Grid). I want the free space to be BELOW the text.

Comment: The approach looks good, but have you tested it? Unfortunately it doesn't work. This time when you shrink the whole window (so there is not enough space), the controls are getting clipped. The inner table is not getting shrunk. I guess when the row is set to "Auto" (outer table in this case) it will never be shrinked, even if it's bigger than the whole table. So you see, it's not that simple. 

PS: I thought I will get the correct answer immediately because one can do ANYTHING in WPF... and there is a lot of experts here but it looks like the WPF is not as flexible as it is said to be.

Comment: In this case it's almost working but the width of the ScrollViewer jumps (when stretching the window horizontally) to match the content text's ActualWidth after wrapping the text. It means that the scrollbar is not moved right with the window border until the next word can fit in line. I've tried to set HorizontalAlignment to Stretch but it's not helping.

Comment: @P.W. See Edit 3 for fixing the jumpy `ScrollViewer` width.

Comment: This one finally WORKS as expected! :) However in the meantime I have discovered much more simple solution. I will attach it as an answer in a moment. I couldn't have done it without you so you've got +1 from me :) Thanks!